# what will happen if my cpu usuage stays 100% for 30 mins or so on linux server

Tags: linux, apache, centos, cpu-usage

I have Amazon Ec2 small instance with 1.7Gb RAM. I have 3 websites running on them.
I have the scripts which does the `web crawling` every day and perform some caluclation.

I have not deployed them yet. But i want to know that if those scripts run for 30 mins and processor usage is 100% what will happen to websites. will they stop working or be slow.

I am not sure

Sites are like 2000 visit per day

Comment: You could `nice` the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is pure CPU, which means almost no I/O usage, you can decrease the priority by `nice`, and your website won't be affected

Comment: guys sorry for that but i didnt get what u mean by pure cpu and no I/o. how can i know about that stuff.